# Function doesnt want to take my argument?

Tags: c++

A friend sent me his threading class.
Now I just want to run a listener but the thread doesnt want to accept the function.
I want to execute the function (defined in `static class Networks`) `THREAD listen(void* args)`. `THREAD` is a `#define THREAD unsigned __stdcall`

```
Networks::init() {
  listenerth = thread();
  listenerth.run(listen, NULL, "listener");
}
```

In `class thread` he defined `run` as `void run( THREAD func(void*), void* args, const char* pname);`

How can I get that to run listen in another thread either?

[edit]
Error message:
main.cpp(19): error C3867: 'Networks::listen': function call missing argument list; use '&Networks::listen' to create a pointer to member

But when i move my mouse to the error place(symbol listen), it shows me this in a tooltip(yes, MS VC++):

> unsigned int __stdcall
>   Networks::listen(void* data)
>
> Error: argument of type "unsigned int
>   (__stdcall Networks::*)(void *data)"
>   is incompatible with parameter of type
>   "unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void*)"

Comment: you should also post the exact error message the compiler gives you.

Comment: Does the first code example of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108631/how-to-pass-a-pointer-to-a-member-function-to-a-c-function/3108745#3108745) help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a C++ class member function as a C callback function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000663/using-a-c-class-member-function-as-a-c-callback-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others say, you can't use a non-static member function here, because it expects a normal function pointer. If you need to call a non-static member (because it needs to access state in the class), then you could use the `args` argument to call it via a static "trampoline" function, something like this:

```
unsigned listen() {/* do the interesting stuff */}

static THREAD call_listen(void* me) 
{
    return static_cast<Networks*>(me)->listen();
}

void init()
{
    listener = thread();
    listener.run(call_listen, this, "listener");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is `listenerth` a member function?  If it is, then it won't work for `run(..)`.

Member functions are not the same as functions declared outside of classes.  They cannot be used with normal function pointers.

Comment: Member functions can be used, but they should be declared static.

Comment: Aww, I just forgot static...
Thanks :D