# c++ passing self to self mistery

Tags: c++, pointers, virtual, self

could you please help me. 
I am passing self to a pure virtual function of itself.

```
n->dataCallback(handler, n, hangup);
```

where n is my class pointer and dataCallback is its own (pure) virtual function (I know it makes no sense, I just wonder why it happens what I describe below).

so now in the declaration:

```
void MyClass::dataCallback(int handler, void *cbData, bool hangup) {
    MyClass *This = (MyClass*) cbData;
 ....
}
```

Now when I compare This (the varaiable above) to this (the pointer of the object) at runtime I get:

1. The values of the poiners (the addresses of the object) are different.
2. When checking a memeber varaible (This->member) I find different values in them. (The correct value is in this, whereas This contains an undefined (to me random) value. Note, that on the caller side the value is of course correct so it seems to magically change during the call itself, and there is no other code in between.

How on earth is this possible? Any Idea?

I've spent 2 hours meditating on this, also asked other programmers with no results.

Comment: Do you use multiple inheritance?

Comment: Please review my edits. Stack Overflow uses [markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and you should at least become familiar with the basic parts like indenting code blocks.

Comment: Would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3725440/140719) or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3108745/140719) help you?

Comment: Thanks for the formatting! This is my first post :) I'll format next time correctly.

Comment: @user1132655: There's a big orange help button next to the post box, that I'd have used my first time on a site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple inheritance, casting a pointer to each of the parent classes may change the pointer address. Consider the following:

```
class A
{
public:
    int a;
};

class B
{
public:
    int b;
};

class C : public A, B
{
};
```

The internal layout of class C will contain two integers `a` and `b`. If you cast a pointer from `C*` to `A*` all is well. If you cast it to `B*`, the pointer will need to be adjusted because the first element in a `B` must be the integer `b`!

If you do a cast where both types are known to the compiler, it will do the adjusting in a way which is invisible to you - it just works. The compiler knows what the proper adjustment should be. When you cast to `void*` this mechanism gets broken.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have a full testcase to work with, but if `MyClass` is polymorphic and related classes exist, then casting can alter the pointer value. The use of `void*` may be breaking that.

Comment: Hi LRO, Yes the class is polymorphic, it uses multiple inheritance, the pure virtual dataCallback is in one such interface (base class). I think I dont understand how can casting alter a value of a pointer, but if it can you probably answered my question. Would be nice to know a bit more about how can casting do that :) Meanwhile Ill change void* to the proper interface and see if it fixes it... Ill be back...

Comment: @user1132655: Mark's explained it quite well.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if `n` is a pointer to a class derived from the one that implements `dataCallback`, and this class has multiple base classes. Only one (non-empty) base object can have the same address as the complete object. Here is an example that illustrates the problem:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    int stuff;
    virtual void f(void * p) {
        std::cout << (p == this ? "GOOD\n" : "BAD\n");
    }
};

struct Other {
    int stuff; 
    virtual void g() {}
};

struct Derived : Other, Base {};

int main()
{
    Derived t;
    t.f(&t);     // BAD: Passing pointer to Derived to member of Base
                 // (but not guaranteed to print "BAD" - layout is not specified)

    Base & b = t;
    b.f(&b);     // GOOD: Passing pointer to Base to member of Base
}
```

Comment: Hi all, thanks everyone for the answer. All answers were correct, I just cant mark each:) When I changed void* to the proper explicit base class Ive got the proper value. I still feel this issue a bit complex (I wouldnt have guess it myself), but Ill do my homework :)