# Cannot call a class method in C signal method

Tags: c++, signals, class-method

I want to use a class method in the signal method

```
signal(SIGALRM, syncro);
```

syncro is the name of another class method.

```
void states::syncro( int parameter )
{

}
```

I try with `syncro`, `&syncro`, `states::syncro`, and `&states::syncro` but all of them throw error messages when compiling.

```
error: argument of type ‘void (states::)(int)’ does not match ‘void (*)(int)’
```

Comment: you need a this pointer to call a class member function. And signal uses the c call convention, that that might also be a problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a C++ class member function as a C callback function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000663/using-a-c-class-member-function-as-a-c-callback-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are able to call only free function or static class function in this case

`signal`'s signature is

```
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);
sighandler_t signal(int signum, sighandler_t handler);
```

That means that it accepts only pointer to free function or static function.

Note, that you should always have an *object* to call *member* function, say, if you have

```
struct S
{
    void method();
}
S obj;
```

you can only call `obj.method()`, but never `S::method()` or `method()`, and pointer to `S::method` has type  `void (S::*)()`.

But if your `S::method()` was declared static you could call it with `S::method()`.

That's why pointers to free functions are incompatible with pointers to member functions.