# how to use SetWindowLong to address a class member function?

Tags: c++, oop, winapi, callback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [To pass a pointer to a member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792664/to-pass-a-pointer-to-a-member-function)

When I move out of the class the `WNDPROC DefEditProc;` and `EditKeyProc` all works ok. But now as I pasted the code it fails compilation with error `error: invalid use of member function (did you forget the '()' ?)`. So my question is how to squeeze this code into class so I do not pollute global namespace ?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <richedit.h>

class richEdit {
  HWND richeditWindow;
  WNDPROC DefEditProc;
  public:

  LRESULT EditKeyProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    return CallWindowProc(DefEditProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
  }
  richEdit() {
    HMODULE richedit_library = LoadLibrary("Msftedit.dll");
    if (NULL == richedit_library) abort();

    HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(0);
    richeditWindow = CreateWindowExW (
      WS_EX_TOPMOST,
      MSFTEDIT_CLASS,
      L"window text",
      WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU | ES_MULTILINE | WS_VISIBLE,
      0, 0, 500, 500,
      NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL
    );
    DefEditProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLong(richeditWindow, GWL_WNDPROC, (long)EditKeyProc);
  }
  ~richEdit() {
    MSG msg;
    while( GetMessageW( &msg, richeditWindow, 0, 0 ) ) {
      TranslateMessage( &msg );
      DispatchMessageW( &msg );
    }
  }
};

int main() {
  richEdit re;
}
```

Comment: `#include <windows.h>` is the worse you can do if you intent to not pollute the global namespace.

Comment: Just a general note, you should use `SetWindowLongPtr` when setting pointers, for forward-compatibility with 64-bit applications.  Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <richedit.h>

class richEdit
{
private:
    HWND richeditWindow;
    WNDPROC DefEditProc;

    static LRESULT CALLBACK EditKeyProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        richEdit *pThis = (richEdit*) GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA);
        return CallWindowProc(pThis->DefEditProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

public:
    richEdit()
        : richeditWindow(NULL), DefEditProc(NULL)
    {
        HMODULE richedit_library = LoadLibrary("Msftedit.dll");
        if (NULL == richedit_library) abort();

        HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(0);
        richeditWindow = CreateWindowExW (
          WS_EX_TOPMOST,
          MSFTEDIT_CLASS,
          L"window text",
          WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU | ES_MULTILINE | WS_VISIBLE,
          0, 0, 500, 500,
          NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL
        );
        if (NULL == richeditWindow) abort();

        SetWindowLongPtr(richeditWindow, GWL_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)this);
        DefEditProc = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLongPtr(richeditWindow, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)&EditKeyProc);
    }

    ~richEdit()
    {
        if (richeditWindow != NULL)
        {
            SetWindowLongPtr(richeditWindow, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)DefEditProc);
            DestroyWindow(richeditWindow);
        }
    }
};
```

Or:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <richedit.h>

namespace myNS
{
    LRESULT CALLBACK richEditKeyProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

    class richEdit
    {
    private:
        HWND richeditWindow;
        WNDPROC DefEditProc;

    public:
        richEdit()
            : richeditWindow(NULL), DefEditProc(NULL)
        {
            HMODULE richedit_library = LoadLibrary("Msftedit.dll");
            if (NULL == richedit_library) abort();

            HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(0);
            richeditWindow = CreateWindowExW (
              WS_EX_TOPMOST,
              MSFTEDIT_CLASS,
              L"window text",
              WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU | ES_MULTILINE | WS_VISIBLE,
              0, 0, 500, 500,
              NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL
            );
            if (NULL == richeditWindow) abort();

            SetWindowLongPtr(richeditWindow, GWL_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)this);
            DefEditProc = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLongPtr(richeditWindow, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)&richEditKeyProc);
        }

        ~richEdit()
        {
            if (richeditWindow != NULL)
            {
                SetWindowLongPtr(richeditWindow, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)DefEditProc);
                DestroyWindow(richeditWindow);
            }
        }
    };

    LRESULT CALLBACK richEditKeyProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        richEdit *pThis = (richEdit*) GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA);
        return CallWindowProc(pThis->DefEditProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are supposed to use a *free function* instead of a *member function*, since *member functions* have an implicit `this` parameter. You will have to declare `EditKeyProc` as `static CALLBACK`, and find another way to pass around the `this` pointer if you need it.

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK EditKeyProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    :::
}
```

Additionally, you may be able to use `SetWindowSubclass` which will take care of proper subclassing and will keep around an extra pointer argument for you.

Comment: Declaring the callback as a static member works on all Windows compilers that I know of, but do be aware that it isn't portable (according to the Standard, there's a potential issue with language linkage).

Comment: @BenVoigt: It should be `__stdcall` as well, right?

Comment: It should be `extern "C" __stdcall`, since that's what Windows expects from pretty much all callback functions.  `CALLBACK` should include `__stdcall`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I have never thought of `extern "C"`, good point...

Comment: Yeah, formally the language linkage `extern "C"` not only affects the exported name but is also part of the function type.  However on Win32, functions with C language linkage and C++ language linkage are the same type anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a pointer to a member function as a window procedure because Windows expects a regular function pointer.  Internally, it won't have enough storage for the member pointer in some cases (they can be up to 16 bytes in MSVC, 32-bit), and it won't know what "this" pointer to use in any case.

If your only interest is avoiding namespace pollution, then the easiest solution is to use a namespace instead of a class.  Otherwise, you'll have to make EditKeyProc a static member of the class and use SetWindowLong to store a copy of the "this" pointer for EditKeyProc to access.

Comment: He's not trying to "store" a member function, he's trying to hand the function pointer to Windows to be called.  Since a pointer-to-member isn't a function pointer, it can't work even if the size is compatible.

Comment: That's a good point.  I'll clarify my answer.