# How to use pointer to member function when when pointer to global function is required?

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I have the following problem. I have to use a function that takes a callback. Implementing the callback is the tricky part, because I need more information beyond that I can extract from the input parameters. I will try to give an example:

```
typedef int (*fptr) (char* in, char* out); // the callback i have to implement
int takeFptr(fptr f, char* someOtherParameters); // the method i have to use
```

The problem is that I need additional info except the "in" parameter to construct the "out" parameter. I tried this approach:

```
class Wrapper {
    public:
        int callback(char* in, char* out){
           // use the "additionalInfo" to construct "out"
        }
        char* additionalInfo;
}

...
Wrapper* obj = new Wrapper();
obj->additionalInfo = "whatIneed";
takeFptr(obj->callback, someMoreParams);
```

I get the following error from the compiler:

> error: cannot convert 'Wrapper::callback' from type 'int (Wrapper::)(char*, char*)' to type 'fptr {aka int(*)(char*, char*)}'

Comment: Ugh. If there's no hope of changing the interface you need to use to take a `std::function` or something, then `bind` or similar can't help you. You'll just have to create a wrapper global function that knows where to find some instance of `Wrapper` and call `callback` on it. This sucks because it effectively forces you to have some kind of global data.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000663/using-a-c-class-member-function-as-a-c-callback-function

Comment: Even if you could convert from a pointer to member to a normal function pointer (you can't in portable code[*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Bound-member-functions.html)), how do you expect the `this` pointer to be available to the callback?

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass what you need to pass, in this case a pointer to a function.

```
::std::function<int (char*, char*)> forwardcall;

int mycallback(char* in, char* out) // extern "C"
{
  return forwardcall(in, out);
}
```

`forwardcall` can contain any functor, for example:

```
forwardcall = [obj](char* in, char* out){ return obj->callback(in, out); };
```

Comment: Why `extern "C"`? There is no indication from the error it is needed.

Comment: @BoBTFish just in case it is needed.

Comment: if the `fptr` callback type isn't declared `extern "C"` then adding it to your callback "just in case" should be an error when you try to pass it to `takeFPtr` (although most compilers don't implement that rule)

Comment: @JonathanWakely I didn't know you could place `extern "C"` into a `typedef`. It is possible?

Comment: You can place it around a typedef, and it affects the type of the function.

Comment: @JonathanWakely that's what I thought, but I decided to just check, and was surprised when it compiled! I have some idea that `extern "C"` becomes part of the type. Ish; I think the wording is a bit funky.

Comment: [dcl.link]/1 "Two function types with different language
linkages are distinct types even if they are otherwise identical."

Comment: @BoBTFish And I've compiled this many times and was surprised it was supposed to trigger an error.