# Is there a way to pass a member function to pthread_cleanup_push?

Tags: c++, pthreads

I want to know the way to pass a member function to `pthread_clean_push`. I don't want to declare the cleanup function as static and pass object's reference to it. Below is the scenario

```
class Foo{
public:
   Foo(string name):name(name){};
   void setBar1(){bar1=malloc(4);sleep(20);};
   void setBar2(){bar2=malloc(10);sleep(50);};
   void cleanBar1(void* arg){free(bar1);};
   void cleanBar2(void* arg){free(bar2);};
private:
   string name;
   void* bar1;
   void* bar2;
};

void* myPThread(void* arg){
   Foo theFoo(*(string*)(arg));
   theFoo.setBar1();
   pthread_cleanup_push(&theFoo.cleanBar1,NULL);   //what is the correct way to
   theFoo.setBar2();
   pthread_cleanup_push(&theFoo.cleanBar2,NULL);   //pass clean functions?
   sleep(100);
   pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
   pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
   return NULL;
}

int main(){
   string biryani="biryani";
   string pappu="pappu";
   pthread_t makeBirayani, makePappu;
   pthread_create(&makeBiryani,NULL,&myPThread,(void*)&biryani);
   pthread_create(&makePappu,NULL,&myPThread,(void*)&pappu);
   pthread_join(makeBiryani,NULL);
   pthread_join(makePappu,NULL);
   return 0;
}
```

I avoided compile-time error ***ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function*** by using `(void(*)(void*))&Foo::cleanBar1`  as the argument to pthread_cleanup_push(). But run-time error(segmentation fault) occurs with multiple threads as it has ambiguity in determining the instance to which the cleanup function belongs. How to invoke the member function like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374847/passing-member-function-pointer-to-member-object-in-c) in this scenario? What is the syntax?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25077611/1171191

Comment: Strictly speaking, you'll have to have a C (or `extern "C"`) function that you pass the object pointer to that calls the member function: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2068048/12711  I'm curious what your objection is.  Certainly, casting a member function pointer to something else won't work.

Comment: No objection. Thank U folk!

Answer (score 3):

`Foo::cleanBar1` and `Foo::cleanBar2` are non-static member functions, which means that they take an implicit first argument, a pointer to the `Foo` instance on which they must be invoked (the `this` pointer). So you cannot pass a pointer to member function to `pthread_cleanup_push` and get the desired behavior.

You'll need to create a dispatcher function that calls the member function you want, and then pass a pointer to that function to `pthread_cleanup_push`. This dispatch function could either be a free function, or a `static` member function of `Foo`. For instance,

```
class Foo{
public:
   Foo(string name):name(name){}
   void setBar1(){bar1=malloc(4);sleep(20);}
   void cleanBar1(){free(bar1);}
   static void bar1_callback(void *arg)
   {
       static_cast<Foo*>(arg)->cleanBar1();
   }

   // ..
private:
   string name;
   void* bar1;
   void* bar2;
};
```

And then pass it to `pthread_cleanup_push` as

```
pthread_cleanup_push(&Foo::bar1_callback, &theFoo);
```

Now the call to `pthread_cleanup_pop` will execute `Foo::bar1_callback` and pass it a pointer to the `theFoo` instance, which will then invoke the `cleanBar1()` member function.

Comment: Thanks! The dispatcher function will do the work but I should try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077611/how-to-use-pointer-to-member-function-when-when-pointer-to-global-function-is-re

Comment: @neckTwi That's essentially the same solution, with the, in this case, unnecessary, abstraction of `std::function` thrown in.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the pthread function [`pthread_cleanup_push`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cleanup_push.html) function you can pass the address of a free function (or possibly `static` to the class `Foo`) to it and a pointer to an object and then route the call to the correct member.

```
void clean_bar_1(void* arg)
{
  Foo* p = static_cast<Foo*>(arg);
  p->cleanBar1();
}
```

And then in `myPThread` function:

```
pthread_cleanup_push(&clean_bar_1, &theFoo);
```

And repeat for the `cleanBar2` method.

Answer (score 0):

The member function needs to know the object for which it is executed.  This is why the standard doesn't allow this direct reference.

Just use a lambda-wrapper, like:

```
 pthread_cleanup_push( [](void*a)->void { reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(a)->cleanBar1(NULL);},
                       &theFoo);    //&theFoo will be passed as argument to the function
```

However you MUST ensure that your theFoo object still exist when the cleanup is called, because you give its adress when you push the cleanup function, and this address will later be used as argument for the cleanup by the lambda function.