# C++ How to call methods within a class as function pointer for TaskScheduler - Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, scheduled-tasks

I try to implement a task which is called within a C++Class and it needs a callback-function. As I'm pretty new to C++ and although I have a rough understanding for pointers this is something I couldn't figure out yet:

I'm using the [TaskScheduler](https://github.com/arkhipenko/TaskScheduler) library to setup everything needed in class I want to call the following function. The normal examples for arduino don't use classes and I'm struggling to get it work in my refactored code.

```
void Weather::setup(std::shared_ptr<Scheduler> s ,int id, String appid, uint32_t interval) 
{
  ...
  weatherTask(interval, TASK_FOREVER, &Weather::updateWeatherCallback, *scheduler, true);
}
```

the updateWeatherCallback-function is implemented in this class too:

```
void Weather::updateWeatherCallback() {...}
```

Asides using the Code above I tried some lambda Variants suggested here on Stackoverflow and simply the following:

```
weatherTask(interval,TASK_FOREVER, [this](){this->updateWeatherCallback;},*scheduler,true);
```

But I figured that my understanding of these answers on Stackoverflow is not good -its more trial and error- which makes searching for "the right answers" difficult

Some details from the TaskScheduler-Library:

```
typedef void (*TaskCallback)();
class Task {
  friend class Scheduler;
  public:
    INLINE Task(unsigned long aInterval=0, long aIterations=0, TaskCallback aCallback=NULL, 
       Scheduler* aScheduler=NULL, bool aEnable=false, TaskOnEnable aOnEnable=NULL, 
       TaskOnDisable aOnDisable=NULL);
...
```

Comment: Just *guessing* here... When you have a member function, you need an object to call it on. Unless `updateWeatherTask` needs to access member variables, you could make the function `static`.

Comment: What is the signature of `weatherTask()`? Also, you might want to read about pointer-to-member-function in C++. They have different semantics compared to regular function pointers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The updateWeatherTask-Method calls other methods of this class that need access to member variables. ;)
I read about the "Object to call it on"-Issue already. However I couldn't figure out how to use this myself

Comment: @DanM.  the signature is as follows:
`Task(Task(unsigned long aInterval=0, long aIterations=0, TaskCallback aCallback=NULL, Scheduler* aScheduler=NULL, bool aEnable=false, TaskOnEnable OnEnable=NULL, TaskOnDisable aOnDisable=NULL);`
Thank you for your suggestion, I'll do some research on it

Comment: @Mina Hm. Is TaskCallback supposed to be a member function or a static one? From the looks of it (and seeing as it's not a template, or is it?) it doesn't look like it can be anything fancy. Is there a way to pass arguments to callback?

Comment: @DanM. as far as I understood it is not possible(but you can always prove me wrong ;P) Its a typedef  in the TaskScheduler-Library: `typedef void (*TaskCallback)();`

Comment: @Mina I figured. When something like in the answer suggested by rmm19433 might be the only clean choice. Though, I think in this case in can be simplified and it can use lambdas, instead of bind + function.

Comment: @DanM.well, the main Problem right now is, that I have problems to figure out how to use lambdas within the class. I would call the updateWeatherCallback with this - however I'm not sure if this is appropriate/working here :/

I also try the suggested answers here - but it'll take some time ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

weatherTask wants a function pointer and not a pointer to a member. A possible way to solve this problem is to create a helper struct and bind the function to a `std::function`.

```
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
struct Callback;

template <typename Ret, typename... Params>
struct Callback<Ret(Params...)> {
   template <typename... Args> 
   static Ret callback(Args... args) {                    
      func(args...);  
   }
   static std::function<Ret(Params...)> func; 
};

template <typename Ret, typename... Params>
std::function<Ret(Params...)> Callback<Ret(Params...)>::func;
```

When creating the weatherTask use the following to bind the member function to your callback:

```
Callback<void(void)>::func = std::bind(&Weather::updateWeatherCallback, this);
TaskCallback func = static_cast<TaskCallback>(Callback<void(void)>::callback);
weatherTask(interval, TASK_FOREVER, func, *scheduler, true);
```

The solution was presented as an anwser to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29817048/9720723) question. Since I cannot comment I decided to provide this as an answer.

---

Alternatively you can make use of a trampoline like function. Therefore you would be required to store an global pointer to your `Weather` object.

```
Weather global_ptr;
```

Then you would be able to create a `weatherTask` using a lambda function.

```
weatherTask(interval, TASK_FOREVER, [](){global_ptr->updateWeatherCallback();}, *scheduler, true);
```

Comment: I implemented the first suggestion
I had to instantiate `func` as `TaskCallback` instead of `callback_t`- both are void-pointers - and `Callback<void(void)>` instead of `Callback<int(int*,int*)>`

Answer (score 0):

While using function pointers above is the old way to do it, the newer way is to make use of the function objects, and the `<functional>` library.  See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional) for an overview of the entire library, with [the examples](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) in `std::function` giving a good "this is how it works" tutorial.

Also look into [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) for this type of thing.  That's also quite useful, and can be stored inside a `std::function` as well.