# reference to non-static member function must be called error

Tags: c++

Im using C++ to create a timer. Ive look up the internet but not find anything that i can understand.Here is my code:

```
struct Timer{
  bool timerRunning;
  int time;
  void Timer_Service(void* param){
    timerRunning = true;
    time = 0;
      while(timerRunning){
        wait(10);
        time += 10;
      }
  }
  void startTimer(){
    Timer_Service((void*)"PROS");
    pros::Task timerservice(Timer_Service,(void*)"PROS");// <- error here "reference to non-static member function must be called"
  }
  void stopTimer(){
    timerRunning = false;
  }
  int getTime(){
    return time;
  }
};
```

How do i solve this error? 
BTW `pros::Task timerservice(Timer_Service,(void*)"PROS");` is a function that initializes a multitask loop.
Thanks all for your kind help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pros::Task` constructor [takes a function pointer](https://pros.cs.purdue.edu/v5/api/cpp/rtos.html#constructor-s).

Function pointers and pointers-to-member-functions are [not the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1000663/560648).

You will have to pass a pointer to a *non-member function* (or a `static` member), ideally a forwarding delegate. You can create a class that contains a `Timer_Service*`, and pass it through the `void*` argument. In fact, in this case, since you *only* need to pass the object pointer, there's no need for a wrapping class.

```
struct Timer
{
  bool timerRunning;
  int time;

  static void Timer_Service_Delegate(void* param) {
     Timer* ptr = reinterpret_cast<Timer*>(param);
     ptr->Timer_Service();
  }

  void Timer_Service() {
    timerRunning = true;
    time = 0;
      while(timerRunning){
        wait(10);
        time += 10;
      }
  }

  void startTimer() {
    pros::Task timerservice(
       Timer_Service_Delegate,
       reinterpret_cast<void*>(this)
    );
  }

  void stopTimer() {
    timerRunning = false;
  }

  int getTime() {
    return time;
  }
};
```

I suspect you'll also need to keep the `pros::Task` in scope, but I don't know enough about the library to train you on that. Refer to its documentation.

Comment: however, i want to create the timer_service for each timer, if using a static member, it will only create the timer_service for the class, not each object

Comment: @EdenCheung No, that's what the delegate's pointer argument is for.

Comment: oh now i see it my browser didnt render the whole thing properly. Thanks alot!

Comment: @EdenCheung No problem. This is quite a common pattern for mixing C-like callback APIs with C++ code, so you'll encounter it again!

Comment: It works, but i dont really understand anything about the delegate ;). Anyways, thanks for your help!

Comment: @EdenCheung Always the first thing you/we should do! That's what it's there for.