Assign member function to base class function pointer
I have to implement a low-level interface for the library which exposes structure with a function pointers like this:
struct Interface {
    int (*IterfaceFn) (int value);
};

Library then expects a function call int InterfaceInit(struct Interface * iface) . The InterfaceFn is used by the library for low-level communication (so it cannot be nullptr).
I wanted to create a class that inherits from Interface and assigns its member function to Interface pointer function:
class Adapter : public Interface
{
public:
    Adapter();

    int adapter_function(int value)
    {
        std::cout << "\tadapter_function " << value << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
};

Adapter::Adapter()
{
    std::cout << "Adapter constructor" << std::endl;
    this->IterfaceFn = &Adapter::adapter_function;    // Error
}

After reading a while I know now that I cannot assign Adapter member functions to function pointers - unless they are static.
My question is: is there any other way I could  create a class that would inherit from Interface so I could pass an Adapter object to the int InterfaceInit(struct Interface * iface) function and have the Interface function pointers in the derived class assigned to Adapter functions?
Or perhaps such problem require some other design pattern than adapter?

Dup/related from comments in SG: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1000663

Since you already understand why the compiler error occurs, then you should also understand why your proposed approach can never work. Given the code shown, the only way to accomplish your goal is to create an intermediate thunk that holds a pointer to the derived object, and then use that thunk for the function pointer. When the thunk is called, it can then call the object method using the stored pointer. Unfortunately, AFAIK there is no way to write such a thunk using straight C++ only, you have to use a small amount of inline assembly  code inside the thunk to manipulate the call stack.

If the IterfaceFn had a different signature then you could create a wrapper: https://godbolt.org/z/Y39aevscv as it is what you want to do is basically not possible to do in a nice way

The shown callback function pointer has no way to tell which Adapter object to choose. Therefore, you must have a global Adapter object that is accessed by a function that serves as a wrapper around the member function call. And this wrapper you can pass as callback function.
